# How to check whether the cursor position is outside of chart control in the windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, cursor-position

I am displaying `tooltip` in the `MS chart`. When moving from chart control to other controls or form free space , `tooltip` is not getting hided.

How to check whether the cursor position is outside of chart control in the windows form?

I tried below code, it did not work for me.

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!chart.ClientRectangle.Contains(chart.PointToClient(new Point(e.X,e.Y))))
    {
        if (ToolTip != null)
            ToolTip.Hide(chart);
     }
 }
```

I put trace and checked, If I move to form free space from chart control, the event is firing, only when moving to other control from chart, `Form1_MouseMove` is not getting called.

How to resolve my problem?

Comment: did you also try `chart.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)` ?

Comment: @Sebastian- If I use Cursor.Position, I am getting the error CS0176: Member 'System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: @Sebastian, I put trace and checked when moving to other control from chart, Form1_MouseMove itself not getting called.

Comment: seems like this is your problem. if its not getting called, the event is not set. in form1.designer.cs must be a line `this.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseMove);`

Comment: @Sebastian the event is set. If I move to form free space from chart control, the event is firing, only when moving to other control from chart, Form1_MouseMove is not getting called

Comment: have you tried to pass the mouse move event through the other controls to the  form?

Comment: Why not use the `chart.MouseLeave` event instead? So you don't need to care what the mouse pointer is hovering after it has left your chart.

Comment: @Jimi, your resolution helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try handling `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events on your target control (the chart in your case, the button in mine).

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const string mouseIsOver = "Mouse is over";
        private const string mouseIsOutside = "Mouse is outside";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var button = new Button { Text = mouseIsOutside, AutoSize = true, Location = new Point(10, 10) };
            button.MouseEnter += (sender, e) => button.Text = mouseIsOver;
            button.MouseLeave += (sender, e) => button.Text = mouseIsOutside;
            this.Controls.Add(button);

        }
    }
}
```

[image]